# In SPA's, is a page a feature module?

Tags: javascript, angular, module, lazy-loading, single-page-application

When creating a Single Page Application in any modern framework you are expected to separate your application structure into modules. Many articles on the subject mention 'feature modules'. A feature module contains everything that is needed to implement a single feature. But are pages automatically a feature module?

My goal is to let Angular load one module, containing everything the user sees on the first pageload, and lazyload all the others. Is making (for instance) a HomeModule, AboutUsModule, ContactModule a good way implement the basic module separation for correct usage of lazy loading?

Comment: Not necessarily, but they are good candidates IMO.

Comment: @estus Thanks for your reply, but that does not make it any more clear. Can you explain when pages are in fact good candidates and when they are not?

Comment: I'd generally move all pages to separate modules, unless the app is really simple. The question is if different pages that are dedicated to same feature should be moved to same module or not. And feature module doesn't necessarily have to be lazy loaded.